# LinqToSql - "insert on submit"

Tags: linq-to-sql, insertonsubmit

I'm trying to insert a row in to one of my tables,
so I look over the web to find an example for using the DATACONTEXT and found this one:

```
protected void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  using (NorthwindDataContext context = new NorthwindDataContext())
  {
    Customer customer = new Customer
    {
      CustomerID = textBoxCustomerID.Text,
      CompanyName = textBoxCompanyName.Text,
      ContactName = textBoxCustomerName.Text,
      ContactTitle = textBoxTitle.Text,
      Address = textBoxAddress.Text,
      City = textBoxCity.Text,
      Region = textBoxRegion.Text,
      PostalCode = textBoxPostalCode.Text,
      Country = textBoxCountry.Text,
      Phone = textBoxPhone.Text,
      Fax = textBoxFax.Text
    };
    context.Customers.InsertOnSubmit(customer);
    context.SubmitChanges();
  }
}
```

but when I try to use it and write : `context.Guides.` - now I can't see the `InsertOnSubmit` method..
does some one know why?

thanks,
yoni.

Comment: what's the type of the Guides property?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a LINQ-to-SQL Classes model (*.dbml), the Guides table must appear in the designer. Otherwise, the Guides class must descend from **System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MetaTable**.

Answer (score -1):

Guides must be an object that doesn't implement the InsertOnSubmit method.